# How to upgrade Intel Graphics driver?

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics

I'm running 18.04 LTS and would like to upgrade my i7 Intel HD Graphics Kaby Lake driver.

I found that in general the following sources should be used:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2018q1-intel-graphics-stack-recipe

**But**: There is no guideline.

- Which of those files presented do I have to download, and how to install them?
- Only the kernel?
- What about the Xserver?

Comment: Please note that Intel has [discontinued](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/update-tool) the "Intel graphics for Linux". There will be no further release after 2018q1 (which targets 17.04). Intel says that the update processes built into Fedora and Ubuntu are mature enough to no longer necessitate a separate update site. Although it sounds more like it is them who can't keep up. In any case 01.org can't be used to update 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Sorry, but if you need to ask how to do that ... just don't. You are more than likely to hose your system. I see already 1 issue: the mesa version in your download is 18.0. Ubuntu 18 is on Mesa 18.1 so it is already a newer version than the one you will download. That might be a problem.

There is a FAR easier method for doing this: use the PPA for it (see this [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) page). It was updated 5 hours ago so you might be in luck. You can add it with this command and it will add all the packages listed on the website; you will need the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

From the description of this PPA:

> This PPA provides updated X (2D) and mesa (3D) free graphics drivers
>   for Radeon, Intel, and Nvidia hardware. Updates packages provide:
>
> - All packages are automatically built twice a day when there are upstream changes
> - Vulkan 1.1+ on recent Intel and Radeon GPU
> - OpenGL 4.5+ support and new OpenGL extensions: http://mesamatrix.net
> - OpenCL support with updated libclc
> - gallium-nine support installed by default.
> - VDPAU and VAAPI Gallium3D accelerated video drivers
> - OpenMAX IL Bellagio and XvMC *only* on zesty and older - disabled since artful due to not being broadly used
> - packages built against latest LLVM
> - Disabled Ubuntu MIR

If the features you mention are not in there yet you could ask about it on the [Phoronix forums](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/opengl-vulkan-mesa-gallium3d/24959-updated-and-optimized-ubuntu-free-graphics-drivers?50038-Updated-and-Optimized-Ubuntu-Free-Graphics-Drivers=). Those are the people that will update the drivers for us.

Comment: That was probably the advise I needed, I could update the drivers successfully.

Comment: @membersound good! :) You will get updates normally now too. So any new build will get offered for installation.

Comment: I know this question seems like an stupid question, but... If I upgrade my installation with all those "new" drivers and I discover that they don't improve any in my system... How can I uninstall all of them and reinstall the "old" standard set of drivers?

Comment: @Juan `ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` to completely revert the `oibaf` ppa changes

Comment: Thanks, rustyx!!! BTW: Is it absolutely necessary to getback to the default drivers if the final result is the same?

Comment: I have a problem with this: I installed the oibaf packages. It has been working so fine and it is upgraded almost every day (but, I don't note some difference with the original Ubuntu drivers). My problen is when I try to uninstall it. The system tells me that the package doesn't exist! So... How could I return to the original Ubuntu drivers?

Comment: you either not got it installed, disabled the ppa or made a typo in the package name ;-) don't think it can be anything else. 1 thing: if you go to the drivers display what does it show as active? installing a driver from here will also uninstall the currrent one

Comment: I installed the package with:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
But... Now, when I type:
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
I get the message:
"ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers doesn't exist"
So...

Comment: Just make two commands out of your one: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` and `sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated drivers using it. But video on youtube still lugs slightly. It played without issues on windows 7. And I'm slightly disappointed that ubuntu 19.10 works slowly than windows 7 on my lenovo g550. On my other PC with nvidia graphic adapter gt220 it works as desired.

Comment: @Gryu that should not be the case: if it works well on w7 Ubuntu should perform the same. g550 is that the matrox from 2001? Have you played with the nvidia software yet? Maybe there are some options to play with.

Comment: @Rinzwind it is from 2009. Google Chrome plays video worse, than Firefox, but FF at video playing starts play it with 2-5 sec video freezes and this situation appears on switching between tabs or windows while video playing. But FF plays perfect in case if processor not fully loaded. It is loaded at 75-90 percents while youtube video playing and video is not hided by other window, or if browser window with youtube is active. While video playing in Chrome, processor is less loaded, but video plays as it seems at 15-20 fps.

Comment: @Rinzwind I've found video with more actions than previous I was playing with. Frequent freezes in FF and Google Chrome seem frustrating)... Maybe there could be kernel related solutions to speed up youtube videos on this machine with ubuntu. But I think, its because of a video driver for Intel is less quality than it is for windows 7.

Comment: @Rinzwind Only `minitube` plays youtube video without issues.

Comment: Nope. Youtube is external: it uses the browser. "But I think, its because of a video driver for Intel is less quality than it is for windows 7. " Unlikely. We lack directx features but the opengl works perfect too. "Only minitube plays youtube video without issues" that would indicate that it is not your system that is the problem.