# OpenGL 4.x support on Ubuntu 18.04.2 using Intel UHD 620

Tags: drivers, apt, xorg, intel-graphics, opengl

I am trying to figure out how to get Ubuntu 18.04.2 to support OpenGL 4.x on my Dell Latitude 7300 laptop with Intel UHD 620 graphics.

From this post:

[How to upgrade Intel Graphics driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065852/how-to-upgrade-intel-graphics-driver)

I gleaned that I need to upgrade my Intel drivers, and the best way to do this was to add a new repository with up-to-date Intel drivers like so:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`

However, when I added that repository and did:

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel`

The output suggested I needed additional dependencies:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried installing the requested dependencies:

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core`

But didn't realize what this was doing:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  intel-gpu-tools libllvm7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  xfonts-100dpi | xfonts-75dpi
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop xorg xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04-dbg xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xserver-xorg-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 18 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

This screwed up my system, since it UNINSTALLED drivers for my trackpad and other critical pieces.  I managed to get the critical pieces re-installed, but I am left wondering, what is the correct procedure to get Intel drivers that support OpenGL 4.x installed?

Answer (score 0):

you have the graphical hw stack on your system.

> xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04

```
sudo apt update
```

Simulation first. sudo apt-get -s install --install-recommends  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all libwayland-egl1-mesa ` Look for conflicts.

then you can istall it.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all libwayland-egl1-mesa
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I did not see any errors indicating conflicts specifically.  It did appear to indicate some "replacement" packages for the ones it was going to remove.  I'll see if I can attach the output here...

Comment: Ok, I ran the command (without simulation) and everything installed without a hitch.  I then ran the `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel` which also succeeded.  I rebooted and `glxinfo | grep version`  does give different output, but it still looks like I don't have OpenGL 4.x support.

Comment: ```server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

Comment: When I run an OpenGL app (Java-based) I get the following output:  ```compile: VertexShader FAILED
0:1(10): error: GLSL 4.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, 3.00 ES, 3.10 ES, and 3.20 ES```

Comment: If you find you're missing OpenGL, this page describes very well how to install OpenGL on Ubuntu and test it to make sure it's working: http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-opengl-ubuntu-linux/