# Can't update OpenGL on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, apt, nvidia, opengl

My GTX TItan X should support OpenGL 4.5: https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-titan-x/specifications

However, I fail to upgrade OpenGL beyond version 1.4

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
> OpenGL version string: 1.4 (3.0 Mesa 18.0.5)
```

I have tried adding two PPAs (one then the other, not at the same time) which should solve the problem: `ubuntu-x-swat` and `oibaf` (taken from example from this answer: [OpenGL/GLSL 4.5 on Ubuntu 19.04, Intel Integrated Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177712/opengl-glsl-4-5-on-ubuntu-19-04-intel-integrated-graphics))

But nothing changes, even after multiple attempts/reboots. For example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade-dist
sudo reboot
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
> OpenGL version string: 1.4 (3.0 Mesa 18.0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I believe I understand what was happening.

The problem is that I was using a display tied to a VNC server (TurboVNC), since the machine is a headless server. I was able to get a VNC server with modern OpenGL enabled by using **VirtualGL**.

- TurboVNC: https://www.turbovnc.org/ (I guess any VNC server would work)
- VirtualGL: https://virtualgl.org/About/Introduction