# Ubuntu 18.04 Install Mesa 19.3 Drivers

Tags: drivers, opengl, mesa

I am trying to install Mesa Drivers 19.3 on my Ubuntu 18.04 Distro for my Radeon RX 580 graphics card. I did run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
// restart system
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

Adding the ppa and upgrading seems to be working fine but it does not seem to set the Mesa drivers correctly:

```
OpenGL version string: 4.6.13581 Compatibility Profile Context
```

I was expecting the see the Mesa version in the OpenGL version string.

Edit:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 6933 MB, largest block: 6120 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 8005 MB, largest block: 6139 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 6933 MB, largest block: 6120 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 8005 MB, largest block: 6139 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 6933 MB, largest block: 6120 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 8005 MB, largest block: 6139 MB
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Radeon RX 580 Series
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.13581 Core Profile Context
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6.13581 Compatibility Profile Context
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: 4.6.13581 Compatibility Profile Context
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: 4.60
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd expect something like that. Try `glxinfo -B` instead.

Comment: While searching for instructions to install Mesa drivers I only found tutorials which included the Mesa version in the OpenGL version string. e.g. [ubuntuhandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/12/install-mesa-19-3-ubuntu-18-04-19-10/) and [askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177712/opengl-glsl-4-5-on-ubuntu-19-04-intel-integrated-graphics). At this point I am confused whether or not I have installed to drivers succesfully.

Comment: Well, this suff is brand new and not well tested. Glitches should be expected. Both commands show mesa version for me, but, apparently, not for you.

Answer (score 0):

[The Oibaf PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) worked for me. It has the latest versions and regularly updates.

You can run these commands to add the PPA to your system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

Comment: `18.04 (bionic) <- obsolete, no longer updated`