# Ubuntu freezes after log in

Tags: 18.04, graphics, intel-graphics

I am a LINUX newbie, tried to install ubuntu on my Thinkpad E550.
 I Followed the same steps as I did with my old (almost ancient) desktop PC, yet I ran into problems.

Whenever I start my Notebook now, it freezes once it reaches the desktop environment (I have auto log in). I googled the symptoms a bit, and apparently this issue is caused by graphic card issues, usually by NVIDIA graphic cards (My notebook has the Intel Graphic chip 5500)

I manipulate the `/etc/default/grub` file and set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`.

While this got rid of the freezing, I cannot change any display settings like brightness.

Has anyone experienced the same issue and could point me in the right direction?

Thanks, and best wishes
pirwlan

Comment: What does this mean: *I can now not change any display settings like brightness.*? You could change brightness or you couldn't. It seems you could by sense, but not by sentence. And what direction do you need? Do you want to change display settings? Maybe you tried to say: *I cannot change any display settings like brightness now*?

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding, and thank you for the correction.

Comment: No problems:)
Have you tried this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1065859/925971 ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried installing these drivers. After installing them, and removing nomodeset from the grub file, it appears to be working. I can log in, I can dim the screen. However, after a couple minutes, the system gets stuck and freezes for a couple seconds, or the system shuts down completely.

Comment: What about kernel version: `uname -a`. What it outputs?

Comment: It outputs: `Linux XXX 5.3.0-26-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 18 16:40:14 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Ok. I have the same kernel version. Have you also tried different desktop managers like Xfce4 or Budgie?